# Find $f(x)$ such that $f^\prime(x) = f(f(x))$

Tags: functional-equations

Is there such a differentiable function $f: R\rightarrow R$ that for

each real $x$ we have $f (x)> 0$ and $f' (x) = f (f (x))$;

Comment: I don't see why such a function shouldn't exist, but it might not be expressible in terms of elementary functions. You might want to read about [functional square roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_square_root). (There's also a lot of questions on stackexchange about it).

Comment: A solution $f$ of the functional equation $f(f(x))=g(x)$ is called an *iterative root* of $g$.

Comment: I don't really see the point of voting down this question, even though this question is short

Comment: I agree with @edm: hence, my upvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No such function does exist.

Assume the contrary. Since $f'(x)=f(f(x))>0$ for any $x\in\Bbb R$, we know that $f$ is increasing.

Mean Value Theorem implies that there exists some $c\in(-1,0)$ such that
$$f(f(c))=f'(c)=f(0)-f(-1)<f(0)$$
Since $f$ is increasing, $f(c)<0$, a contradiction.